# HttpListener transfer to location without redirect

Tags: c#, vb.net, httplistener

I'm using HttpListener behind a Nginx as proxy, and using Nginx to serve static files.
I want to redirect a request to a resource inside the code without disclosing the resulting location or perform a redirection, something similar to Server.Transfer in ASP.net.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Then download the resource from original location and pass it to the client.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that option. But I want to delegate the job to the web server and not using my app resources.